# Why am I getting an InvalidCastException here?

Tags: string, visual-studio-2013, string-concatenation

I'm trying to write code to print out "Row (0 to 3): ".

Here's my code:

```
ReadOnly gridSize As Integer = 4
Dim s1 As String
s1 = "Row (0 to " & (gridSize - 1) & "): "
WriteLine(s1)
```

I'm getting an InvalidCastException with the following error at the last line, when the machine tries to print out the string:

> Conversion from string "Row (0 to 3): " to type 'Integer' is not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integer is not a String.
How about using gridSize.ToString() ?

Comment: Or suitable for you: (xxxx - xxx).ToString()

Comment: Like this? `s1 = "Row (0 to " & (gridSize - 1).ToString() & "): "` I get the same error sadly

Comment: Hm should work (in C# anyway), try & CStr(gridsize - xx) &

Comment: Tried that too - no luck. It seems that the error occurs on the WriteLine(s1) line, is there maybe a way to specify that you want it to input a String?

Comment: Hm... do you have any specification of the WriteLine method? Is it Writing to the console?

Comment: No you were right; I just had to write Console.WriteLine rather than just WriteLine. It fixed my problem :)